# How to mock a primitive const value using jest and restore the mock?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

So suppose I have a file named "config.js":

```
export const DELAY_SECONDS = 5;
```

And when doing the tests:

```
// Ignore the delay when doing the tests.
jest.mock("/path/to/config", () => ({ DELAY_SECONDS: 0 }))
```

But I also want to test if the original value works:

```
it('should work with delay', () => {
    // Use original value implicitly.
    a_function_uses_DELAY_SECONDS()
    expect(...).toBe(...)
})
```

How could I restore that mock? Or is there a better way to implement the mock?

I have tried something below and none of them works:

```
it('should work with delay', () => {
    jest.unmock() // Doesn't work at all, don't even know what does this method do.
    // Use original value implicitly.
    a_function_uses_DELAY_SECONDS()
    expect(...).toBe(...)
})
```

```
it('should work with delay', () => {
    jest.mock("/path/to/config", () => ({ DELAY_SECONDS: 5 })) // Call the mock again doesn't work
    // Use original value implicitly.
    a_function_uses_DELAY_SECONDS()
    expect(...).toBe(...)
})
```

```
it('should work with delay', () => {
    const config = require("/path/to/config").default;
    config.DELAY_SECONDS = 5; // Won't work, as it is a constant, cannot modify
    // Use original value implicitly.
    a_function_uses_DELAY_SECONDS()
    expect(...).toBe(...)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

E.g.

`config.js`:

```js
export const DELAY_SECONDS = 5;
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { DELAY_SECONDS } from './config';

function main() {
  return DELAY_SECONDS;
}

export { main };
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
describe('64473533', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should work with delay - original', () => {
    const { main } = require('./main');
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe(5);
  });
  it('should work with delay - mocked', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({ DELAY_SECONDS: 0 }));
    const { main } = require('./main');
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64473533/main.test.js
  64473533
    ✓ should work with delay - original (445ms)
    ✓ should work with delay - mocked (2ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 config.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.694s
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Is there a way to revert this progress? Oh, I got it. I can `doMock` in the `beforeEach` and only `resetModules` in the test I want right?

Comment: @Sraw It's better to mock per need basis like the answer suggests. And doing resetModules not every time can make tests unpredictable. If you need to keep the access to original implementation that won't be affected by doMock, import it at top level.